# self signed root cert can not be verified with openssl - error 18 at 0 depth lookup

Tags: tls, certificates

I'm simply trying to create a self signed cert. I created a root cert from which I created

- server key + cert  and
- client key + cert

While connecting to TLS server installed with server key + server cert, 
client fails with message `Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized`.

To debug when I want to verify my root cert itself, I get `error 18 at 0 depth lookup`.

http://gagravarr.org/writing/openssl-certs/errors.shtml mentions "#2 could be because certificate is self signed and not trusted" **but** not sure how can I verify the root certificate.

Below is my config to create root cert,

root-ca.config

```
[req]
default_bits = 2048
prompt = no
default_md = sha256
distinguished_name = dn

[ dn ]
C=US
ST=Seattle
L=Seattle
O=Duwamish
OU=SC
emailAddress=some.email@gmail.com
CN =localhost
```

cert

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:1024 -sha1 -keyout rootkey.pem -out rootreq.pem -config root-ca.conf
openssl x509 -req -in rootreq.pem -sha1 -signkey rootkey.pem -out rootcert.pem
```

Then I copied root cert to `/etc/pki/tls/certs/` (Redhat os).

```
cp rootcert.pem /etc/pki/tls/certs/
sudo update-ca-trust extract

[root@ip-172-18-20-233 conf3]# ll /etc/pki/tls/certs
total 24
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root     root       49 Apr 17 07:59 ca-bundle.crt -> /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root     root       55 Apr 17 07:59 ca-bundle.trust.crt -> /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/openssl/ca-bundle.trust.crt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root     root      610 Feb 28  2017 make-dummy-cert
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root     2388 Feb 28  2017 Makefile
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root     root      829 Feb 28  2017 renew-dummy-cert
-rw-r--r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 1688 Aug 31 22:58 restapi-root-ca.cert
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root     1342 Sep  1 05:58 restapi-server.cert
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root      944 Sep  1 08:00 rootcert.pem
```

**verify**

```
openssl verify rootcert.pem 
rootcert.pem: /C=US/ST=Seattle/L=Seattle/O=Duwamish/OU=SC/emailAddress=some.email@gmail.com/CN=localhost
error 18 at 0 depth lookup:self signed certificate
OK
```

Comment: Related to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295585/openssl-certificate-verification-on-linux ?

Comment: While the question seems to ask *"how can I tell it to trust while verifying"* you don't offer any information what *"it"* is. But, the trust needs to be setup as the client site  and thus the actual ways to add this trust depend on what *"it"* is. Which means your question can not be answered.

Comment: @M'vy True, I started my work from that post [openSSL certificate-verification on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13307011/432903), but I Can not verify the `rootcert.pem`

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I basically meant to ask how can I verify my root x509 certificate? I eventually want my client to trust to server certificate but above question is verifying the root certificate. Im not sure if Im making any sense.

Comment: @prayagupd: if you want to create a root certificate then it needs to be a CA certificate and thus have `basicConstraints CA:true`. Your certificate does not have this. But, there are enough guides on the internet on how to create your own CA so just follow these.

Comment: Thx. I'm following couple of posts where authors are creating root cert and and using root.key, create server and client certs. And some authors like you said (https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/create-the-root-pair.html) are creating CA.cert and then intermediate.cert which then creates server and client certs. I still need to figure out the second way.

Comment: I had this issue using openssl 1.0.1, switching to 1.1.1 and generating the certificate again removed this error for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering to my own very newbie 101 question. I had to install root cert so that I could trust it.

I was updating redhat ca after copying my root cert to `/etc/pki/tls/certs`, but somehow it was not reloaded. I ended up copying the PEM manually to `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt`.